# R merge function is unable to find shared matches between data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Hi I have the following two data frames:

```
# dataframe 1 --> clst1_trimmed

> head(clst1_trimmed)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  GeneName Clst.1
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 Cd74      1.20 
2 Lyz2      1.02 
3 Malat1    0.196
4 Ftl1      0.577
5 H2-Ab1    1.04 
6 B2m       0.639`

# dataframe2 --> immgen_trimmed
> head(immgen_trimmed)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ProbeSetID GeneName Description                                      Cell.A Cell.B Cell.C
       <int> <fct>    <fct>                                             <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1   10344620 Cd74     " predicted gene 10568"                            15.6   15.3   17.2
2   10344622 Cd74     " predicted gene 10568"                           240.   255.   224. 
3   10344624 Lyz2     " lysophospholipase 1"                            421.   474.   349. 
4   10344633 Malat1   " transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1"      802.   950.   864. 
5   10344637 Flt1     " ATPase H+ transporting lysosomal V1 subunit H"  199.   262.   167. 
6   10344653 Cd3e     " opioid receptor kappa 1"                         14.8   12.8   18.0
```

I'd like to merge these together based on the shared `GeneNames`. I tried the following, and it worked:

```
merged <- merge(clst1_trimmed, immgen_trimmed)
 merged
  GeneName    Clst.1 ProbeSetID                                   Description    Cell.A    Cell.B
1     Cd74 1.1954372   10344622                          predicted gene 10568 239.86400 255.05600
2     Cd74 1.1954372   10344620                          predicted gene 10568  15.62080  15.33110
3   Ifitm3 1.7265938   10344674  family with sequence similarity 150 member A   9.40599   9.22875
4     Lyz2 1.0227826   10344624                           lysophospholipase 1 420.51800 474.19000
5   Malat1 0.1962251   10344633     transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 801.62400 949.96800
    Cell.C
1 223.8960
2  17.2005
3  10.3231
4 349.0890
5 863.5060
```

However, merging the two large data frames with the same approach fails:

```
> dim(sel_clst)
[1] 984   2
> dim(immgen_log2)
[1] 24922   212

merge2 <- merge(sel_clst, immgen_log2)
  str(merged2)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  213 variables:
 $ GeneName                      : Factor w/ 984 levels "0610012G03Rik",..: 
 $ Cluster.1.Log2.Fold.Change    : num 
 $ ProbeSetID                    : int 
 $ Description                   : Factor w/ 21246 levels " "," 1-acylglycerol-3-phosphate O-acyltransferase 1 (lysophosphatidic acid acyltransferase alpha)",..: 
 $ X.proB_CLP_BM.                : num 
 $ X.proB_CLP_FL.                : num 
 $ X.proB_FrA_BM.                : num
```

I think the problem is `GeneName` isn't recognized correctly in the `immgen_log2` data frame. I looked up a gene that I know should be present in both data frames `"Cd74"`, but it didn't show up in the `immgen_log2` data frame.

```
> "Cd74" %in% sel_clst$GeneName
[1] TRUE
> "Cd74" %in% immgen_log2$GeneName
[1] FALSE
```

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: Did you notice the leading space in one of your variable's values? Neither`"Cd74 "` nor `" Cd74"` would match `"Cd74"`. I have a function named `trim` that removes leading and trailing spaces. I'd suggest first coercing all key columns to "character" and then trimming your values before reattempting a match.

Comment: Maybe also look at your data import commands for an upstream fix.

Comment: or use `levels(df$var) <- trimws(levels(df$var))` (but always better to fix upstream)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: I'm always a bit leery of using `levels<-`, but this does look like a reasonable application of it. It would need to be done on both dataframes.

Comment: Yep, that space was the problem. Didn't catch it. I guess the question becomes obsolete with that realization. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (after making a backup copy of these dataframes):

```
levels(sel_clst$GeneName) <- trimws( levels( sel_clst$GeneName ))
levels(immgen_log2$GeneName) <- trimws( levels( immgen_log2$GeneName ))
merge2 <- merge(sel_clst, immgen_log2)
```

Sometimes the `read.csv` function fails to do the trimming at the time of data input so running `trimws` across all your read.csv operations might be a sanity preservation step for future efforts. For the TL;DR version you should set `strip.white=TRUE` as a parameter whenever you use `read.csv`. I'd go so far as to say you should overwrite your copy of read.csv with:

```
read.csv <- 
       function ( ...){ utils::read.csv(..., strip.white=TRUE) }
```

There is an `options`-parameter that is accessible with `default.stringsAsFactors()` that would allow you to avoid much of the newbie confusion about factor-creation, but there's no default setting that can be adjusted for `strip.white`.

Review this transcript:

```
> dat <- read.csv(text= "hd1 , hd2, hd3\n 1, a ,   c\n1,b,d\n")
> dat
  hd1 hd2  hd3
1   1  a     c
2   1   b    d
> dput(dat)
structure(list(hd1 = c(1L, 1L), hd2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c(" a ", 
"b"), class = "factor"), hd3 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("   c", 
"d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("hd1", "hd2", "hd3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
> dat <- data.frame(
             lapply(read.csv(text= "hd1 , hd2, hd3\n 1, a ,   c\n1,b,d\n"), 
                    trimws)
                    )
# could also have used a two step process starting with the original `dat` 
# dat[] <- lapply(dat, trimws)   .... the `[]` preserves structure

> dat
  hd1 hd2 hd3
1   1   a   c
2   1   b   d
> dput(dat)
structure(list(hd1 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    hd2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    hd3 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("hd1", 
"hd2", "hd3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you pass `trimws` as an argument to my code here: `immgen_dat <- tbl_df(read.csv("RequestedImmGenData2018-04-20_18-48-38.csv"))`

Comment: Perhaps: `immgen_dat <- as_tibble( lapply( read.csv("RequestedImmGenData2018-04-20_18-48-38.csv"), trimws))`. I don't think `tbl_df` (now deprecated) or `as_tibble` will automagically do the trimming. The `data.table::fread` will do so.

Comment: Can you please explain in a few words why you need to structure the data frame `as_tibble` for this to work?

Comment: `lapply` jsut returns a list without any other class attribute. Using either `data.frame` or `as_tibble` restores the "data.frame" class attribute. I suggest you look into `fread`. It's faster and safer.

Comment: you can use parameter `strip.white = TRUE` in `read.table`, and I would suppose in `read.csv` as well.

Comment: `strip.white = TRUE` worked within `read.csv` for removing the leading spaces. Is there a reason/advantage of using `strip.white` over `lapply(read.csv("..."), trimws))` approach?

Comment: I don't think it'll make any difference, it has the same purpose, I guess there's a possibility that they treat other blank characters differently (such as `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and special spaces).

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference in the long run, but I do think it would be faster to use strip.white=TRUE. The strip.white parameter is passed to scan and then to `.Internal(scan(...)`.I'm also puzzled why `strip.white=TRUE` is not the default setting for `read.csv`. It _is_ implicitly the behavior for `read.table`.